# Shrink figure only when necessary?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, scaling

I'm writing a report where I have generated and included several TikZ pictures which I also want to use in my beamer presentation. However, some of the pictures (but not all) which fit in the report are too large for the slides. Hence, I wonder if there is any package or macro which shrinks a figure if it is too large, but leaves it alone if it already fits.

If the answer only works for TikZ then that's fine. I don't mind shrinking texts and lines along with the entire figure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package can be used to scale (or otherwise adjust) images or any other content, like a `tikzpicture` in several ways. You need the `max size={<width>}{<height>}` option in your case, which does exactly what you requested, i.e. only shrink the content if it is larger than the given width and/or height. It always keeps the aspect-ratio.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% ..

\begin{adjustbox}{max size={.95\textwidth}{.8\textheight}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ..
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```

---

This is also possible for images. Here the same key can be used with `\adjustimage`:

```
\adjustimage{max size={..}{..}}{<imagefilename>}
```

which uses `\includegraphics` internally, but wraps it in a `\adjustbox` macro.

Comment: PS: A related question which I also solved with `adjustbox` is [Scale included graphics to the higher ratio instead of the lower for given width, height](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25988/scale-included-graphics-to-the-higher-ratio-instead-of-the-lower-for-given-width). It is the other way around (scaling up if required) plus some more stuff (cropping).

Comment: Ah excellent. But why do you use `.95\textwidth` instead of the whole `\textwidth`?

Comment: Just personal taste. The full text width sometimes looks a little wide. You can of course use `\textwidth`. Unfortunately the `\textheight` includes the title and sub-title (if present) as well. There heights are theme specific and so you have to guess the maximum usable height.

Comment: Ah. Well, so far none of my pictures are taller than they are wide.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent package, Martin. Adjustbox saved me from long tinkering of the tikz picture size.

Answer (score 2):

works also for images which are wrongly set to a width greater than the text width:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\let\Includegrfx\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \sbox\IBox{\Includegrfx[#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\IBox>\textwidth\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\IBox}\else
                           \usebox\IBox\fi}
\parindent=0pt % for demo
\begin{document} 
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\includegraphics[width=3\textwidth]{tiger}

\end{document}
```