# Use \textwidth for Image width Only when it outgrows the page

Tags: graphics, scaling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shrink figure only when necessary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/shrink-figure-only-when-necessary)

Consider that you have this:

```
\includegraphics{some_image_in_pdf.pdf}
```

This will now take its original width, but if you want it to take up 100% of the text width you do it like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{some_image_in_pdf.pdf}
```

How about if you want to include images and use their original size if they fit, otherwise have it resized?

In this example, the second image should get `[width=\textwidth]` because it is going to exceed the bounds of the document.

```
\includegraphics{some_image_in_pdf.pdf}
\includegraphics{some_image_in_pdf_that_is_too_wide.pdf}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides a `max width=\textwidth` key option for this. So, you can use

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
...
\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth]{some_image_in_pdf.pdf}
\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth]{some_image_in_pdf_that_is_too_wide.pdf}
```

Comment: Does not work in twocolumn mode of document class book.

Comment: @gentlesea: For `twocolumn` mode you're probably interested in `max width=\columnwidth`.

Answer (score 2):

works also for images which are wrongly set to a width greater than the text width:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\let\Includegrfx\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \sbox\IBox{\Includegrfx[#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\IBox>\textwidth\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\IBox}\else
                           \usebox\IBox\fi}
\parindent=0pt % for demo
\begin{document} 
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\includegraphics[width=3\textwidth]{tiger}

\end{document}
```