# Tikz's picture: out of the page margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth)
>   [Shrink figure only when necessary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30312)

As you can see the third rectangle is out of the right margin...how can I fix this issue?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.5,4.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=70mm]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.5,4.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=140mm]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.5,4.5);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean how to resize the whole picture down to the text width, right? See [Shrink figure only when necessary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30312/2975) and [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6388/2975) This question should be closed as duplicate if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `scale` option to `tikzpicture`, or you can also use `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package; a little example of the latter, making the `tikzpicture` span the whole `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.5,4.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=70mm]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.5,4.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=140mm]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.5,4.5);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, but `adjustbox` is even better because it doesn't read the whole thing has macro argument and can be configured to only scale if required. The `adjustbox` environment also uses by default. See [Shrink figure only when necessary?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30315/2975)