# tikz \draw going beyond page margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I am trying to have a specific figure fit within the required margins. I drew 2 lines with the text "Reconstruction" and "Forecasting" as shown below but they somehow ignore the margins. I have tried the solution from [Tikz's picture: out of the page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54253/tikzs-picture-out-of-the-page-margin) but it does not seem to work in my case.

I am finding it impossible to produce a MWE so I am pasting a copy of the overleaf project here. The problem is in `4)experiments.tex` lines 575 and 576. https://www.overleaf.com/7541219539fgfjvjckfvzj#aff1f6. I hope to get some help please.

```
\draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagea.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagec.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};
\draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imaged.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imageh.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Forecasting};
```

[image]

Edit: Here is a longer snippet of the code that produces the figure. It can also be viewed in the overleaf project from lines 404 to 579.

```
\definetrim{kit_rgbd}{8cm 0 6cm 2cm} % {left bottom right top}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagea) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0168.png}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Mod};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagea.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0180.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageb.north west) {\tiny{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagec) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0195.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagec.north west) {\tiny{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0207.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imaged.north west) {\tiny{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagee) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0219.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagee.north west) {\tiny{5}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imagef) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0231.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imagef.north west) {\tiny{6}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imageg) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0243.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageg.north west) {\tiny{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (imageh) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/mod/0255.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (imageh.north west) {\tiny{8}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

% % % % %
% ours  % 
% % % % %

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0168.png}};
    \begin{scope}[anchor=north west]
        \node[draw,fill=white,rotate=90] at (0,0) {Ours};
    \end{scope}
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image1.north west) {\tiny{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0180.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image2.north west) {\tiny{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0195.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image3.north west) {\tiny{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0207.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image4.north west) {\tiny{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0219.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image5.north west) {\tiny{5}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0231.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image6.north west) {\tiny{6}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0243.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image7.north west) {\tiny{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,lbl/.style = {draw, outer sep=2\pgflinewidth, fill=white, anchor=#1}]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblack[width=\imagewidth,kit_rgbd,clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/subject_6/task_3_k_pouring/take_8/ours/0255.png}};
    \node[lbl=north west,draw,fill=white] at (image8.north west) {\tiny{8}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\vspace{0.2cm}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% contact classification  %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}   
    \footnotesize{True Left} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/true_l.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \footnotesize{Pred Left} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/pred_l.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \footnotesize{True Right} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/true_r.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \footnotesize{Pred Right} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{figures/experiments/kit_rgbd/pred_r.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabular}

% % % % %
% bars  %
% % % % %

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}

    % min t = 168
    % max t = 255

    % take (t - min) / length
    % length = 84
    
    % image1 t=0
    \def\time1{0}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image1.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar2.south west)+(\n1,0)$);

    % image2 t=40
    \def\time1{0.13793103448275862}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image2.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar2.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image3 t=70
    \def\time1{0.3103448275862069}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image3.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar2.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image4 t=92
    \def\time1{0.4482758620689655}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image4.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image5 t=120
    \def\time1{0.5862068965517241}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image5.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image6 t=160
    \def\time1{0.7241379310344828}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image6.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image7 t=190
    \def\time1{0.8620689655172413}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image7.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image8 t=220
    \def\time1{1.0}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image8.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);

    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagea.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imagec.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Reconstruction};
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imaged.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.1cm]imageh.north east)node[midway,above] {\strut Forecasting};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The line and text is overshooting the page margin.

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. If you not able to do this, how we can see, what you doing?

Comment: @Zarko i have included a longer snippet of the code. It can also be viewed in the link to the overleaf project which I felt would be better since it directly showcases the problem.

Comment: @Kong External links might rot and your question will become useless to future users with the same problem. Always include a small, but compilable test document directly in your question and not as an external link.

Comment: Moreover, we do not know what `\frameincludegraph...` is doing. There are instructions on how create a useful MWE here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Do you realize that `\def\time1{0.7241379310344828}` **does not** define a macro named `\time1`? Macro names can't have digits in them

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Apparently I not understand what OP is after. So one more guessing. If this time I again misunderstand you, I will delete my answer

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,top=0.5in,%
            headheight=6\baselineskip,headsep=2\baselineskip,includehead,%
            ]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{%
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={cX[c, m]}, rowsep=5pt}
Reconstruction
    &   &   Forecasting \\
    \cmidrule{1-1}
    \cmidrule{3-3}           
\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-duck}
    &   &   \includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-duck}
    \end{tblr}
        }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows part of page layout)

Comment: sorry what i meant by margins was that the text and lines I drew are going above the top page margin. They are ignoring the page margins. The drawings and figures need to be pushed below the margin.

Comment: Please, provide a sketch, what you after. Is maybe  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284825/ close to what you after?

Comment: i have updated my post to include 2 figures side by side. The one on the left does not overshoot the margin, the one on the right overshoots the margin.

Comment: @Zarki, you are probably right this time --- the problem is that not knowing what the several macros of the OP are doing, it's impossible to spot the error. The `\def\time1{whatever}` is an evident one, but $DEITY knows... 