# How can I set the defaults for pictures in my document?

Tags: graphics

I was wandering if there is a command that will let you define the size of graphics globally throughout then entire document. Most of my images are photos and should all be the same size and it would be good if I could change one thing that will affect the size of them all, rather than having to do it manually. For the odd picture here and there that has different dimensions I can adjust their size manually.

<sub>Question content copied with permission from [a post on /r/latex](http://redd.it/2uwuy6).</sub>

Comment: Related: [Setting a global limit for image dimensions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145293/5764)

Comment: @texenthusiast Looks like a dupe to me.  Funny – didn't come up in my searching.  At least this question will help those who search like I do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `graphicx`'s keyval group:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=25cm}
```

Stick that in your preamble *after* you load `graphicx`. If you're not loading it explicitly, put it right after `\begin{document}`.

After this, you shouldn't have to supply the `width` key at all when you use `\includegraphics`. Of course, if you do supply the `width` key, that value will take precedence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=.25\linewidth} % or whatever

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```