# How do I control the exact dimension of a picture in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, lengths

This question is pretty simple: I'd like to have the possibility to get the exact size of a picture in LaTeX with, for example, the macro `\the`.

In fact, I've founded the way `\settoheight{}` and so on, but it didn't work at all. What I've got doesn't match with what I can see in the image properties (I suppose that's the name in English). The result: 8pt versus 1300 pixels. It's may be a mis-use...

Edit: In the end, my aim was to find a way to fit the picture in LaTeX. If width and height were both less than the dimensions of the body, then it should just be centred. It look like this :

---

Require:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
```

Code (pretty ugly, I agree):

```
% Centrering+fitting for image, with captation and label (not auto)
\newlength\imageheight
\newlength\imagewidth
\newcommand{\pic}[3]{%
\settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics{pictures/#1.png}}%
\settowidth\imagewidth{\includegraphics{pictures/#1.png}}%
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\imagewidth > \textwidth}}{\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\imageheight > \imagewidth}}{\par\vspace{0.95em}%
\begin{figure}
    \centering\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{pictures/#1.png}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{#3}
\end{figure}%
\par\vspace{0.95em}}{\par\vspace{0.95em}%
\begin{figure}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{pictures/#1.png}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{#3}
\end{figure}%
\par\vspace{0.95em}}}{\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\imageheight > \textheight}}{\par\vspace{0.95em}%
\begin{figure}
    \centering\includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight]{pictures/#1.png}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{#3}
\end{figure}%
\par\vspace{0.95em}}{\par\vspace{0.95em}%
\begin{figure}
    \centering\includegraphics{pictures/#1.png}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{#3}
\end{figure}%
\par\vspace{0.95em}}}}
%
```

To use it : put your png files in a "pictures" directory, then, just simply call the picture like this : `\pic{name_whitout_extension}{Captation_if_needed}{Label_if_needed}`.

---

Edit 2 :

Thanks to Martin Scharrer's `easyfig` package, I've got a more or less 1,6 times faster solution to put my pictures, centred, with the perfect size.

CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easyfig

VC: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/easyfig

Version v1.2 – 2012/05/15

---

This could be useful for some others, I hope.

Comment: 8pt seems really small, but still, you can't directly compare pt and pixels. 1pt is a physical length (1/72.27 inches), pixels are logical units. The conversion between pixels and points depends on the resolution of the image (which is usually measured in "pixels per inch", or "dpi").

Comment: Then, I guess it's depend of my paper dimension, since I work with PDF. Thanks for it. Still, it's not really the needed answer.

Comment: If an image has a natural resolution of 300dpi and it says about itself that its width is 1200 pixels, then the natural width (as seen by LaTeX) is 4 inches. At 600dpi the width would be 2 inches.

Comment: @Julien: No, it depends on the resolution of the image. There should be a tag in your image metadata. If you have ImageMagick installed, you can run `identify -verbose <image filename>` to see it, or you could look at the metadata in IrfanView by pressing `I`. If no resolution is set, LaTeX assumes 72dpi.

Comment: @Julien: You seem to want to rescale the image dependent on how wide it is. Note that this can be easily done using my `adjustbox` package. It can add `min width` and `max width` options to `\includegraphics` to only scale an image if it is wider or narrower than a certain width.

Comment: @Jake, Julien: If this is about scaling down to large images than it is a duplicate of [Scale included graphics to the higher ratio instead of the lower for given width, height](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25988/2975) or [Scale (resize) large images (graphics) that exceed page margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6073/2975)

Comment: Note that `adjustbox` now includes keys to set captions and label as well as turning the content into a float. Also, check out my other package `easyfig`, which also might be useful for you.

Comment: I'll try it and it's awesome ! It does what I wanted in a better way (see : tex.stackexchange.com/a/53509/13993, in the comments). Thank you very much !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If all you want is to limit the width of your image to some maximum value (like `\linewidth`), you could simply use the approach described in the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-grmaxwidth):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{largebottle}

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{largesidebottle}
\end{document}
```

---

To actually measure and output the dimensions, `\settoheight` and `\settowidth` should work. You can convert the `pt` units to other units using the `printlen` package, as Werner pointed out in the comments.

[image]

ImageMagick (`identify -verbose bottle.jpg`) shows the geometry to be 1408x714 pixels, with a resolution of 300x300 pixels per inch, which translates to `1408 px/300 px per in*72.27 pt per in=339.1872 pt` and `714 px/300 px per in * 72.27 pt per in = 172.0026 pt`.

```
\documentclass[11pt ]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}

\newlength\imageheight
\newlength\imagewidth

\begin{document}

\settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics{bottle}}
\settowidth\imagewidth{\includegraphics{bottle}}
\includegraphics{bottle}

Height: \the\imageheight\ (\printlength{\imageheight})

Width: \the\imagewidth\ (\printlength{\imagewidth})

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps suggest the use of [`printlen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/printlen) in order to print a length in a different unit. Even better, extend it to print a length in `px`! Also, you don't need the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc).

Comment: Thanks ! It's work pretty fine, thus, the value it give to is ... more or less the pixels value. But I don't need to be perfectly accurate. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Werner: Good idea, and thanks for the note about the `calc` package! However, to convert to `px`, one would need to know the image resolution, and I don't know how to read that from the image file within LaTeX.

Comment: @Julien: It's not "more or less" pixel values: The difference between the ImageMagick information and the `\settoheight` value is `0.001pt`, which is `0.000014 inch` (that's *really* small!). At a resolution of `300dpi`, that's a difference of `0.004 pixels`.

Comment: Herm. Based of my technique. Anyway, what I was working on is now done thanks to Jake. Again, thanks. I'll post (if usefull) what it was. By the way, How do I put that's an "over" question ?

Comment: @Jake: `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` provides an `max width` key for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: What does `\Gin@nat@width` mean?

Comment: @jake thanks for the snippet, I use it to fix my [file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323307/rendering-of-jpeg-file-wrong-size) - and if anybody sees what could be wrong with my  [issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323307/rendering-of-jpeg-file-wrong-size) I appreciate to know.

Answer (score 12):

LaTeX doesn't use pixels. Pixels aren't a print format. `pdflatex` allows a `px` unit but this is simply converted to points (`pt`) like everything else in TeX. The pixel-to-point ratio depends on the image *density* which is in dots-per-inch (DPI). By default 72 DPI are used. A TeX point is 1/72.27 inches and a PostScript/PDF point (`bp` in TeX) is 1/72 inches. If your image has a large DPI value but `pdflatex` can't read that from the images meta-data this conversion might be wrong (because 72 DPI are assumed) and your image is sized incorrectly. Sometimes simply converting your image or opening and saving it fixes the meta-data.

---

About how to measure all dimensions of the image:

Don't include the image multiple times to measure its different sizes. Store it manually in a box (e.g. `\mybox`) and then you can access the box dimensions directly using `\ht\mybox` (height), `\wd\mybox` (width) and `\dp\mybox` (depth). All the `\setto...` macros you have mentioned do exactly the same with a temp box.

```
\newsavebox\mybox

\newcommand{\pic}[1]{%
   \sbox\mybox{\includegraphics{#1}}%
   Height: \the\ht\mybox
   Width: \the\wd\mybox
   Depth: \the\dp\mybox % For images usually 0 except if rotated 
   \ifdim\wd\mybox>.6\textwidth
     % width is larger than 60% of the text width ...
   \fi
   % Insert the image:
   \usebox\mybox
}
```

You can also need the `\@tempboxa` box register (requires `\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother`) or directly the box register number `0`: `\sbox0{...} \ht0 ...`

Comment: Wouaw. Didn't knew so much. Well, since I'm not an informatician, can't tast the exact details, but is this way a more simple one, or a more optimized one (I mean, this will go faster with more accuracy) ?

Comment: It's both more simple (i.e. lower level) and (therefore) faster. The `\settosomething` macros are higher-level wrappers around code like this.

Answer (score 11):

Although the question asks how to do this in LaTeX, I am also adding an answer to show how to do this using a high level interface in ConTeXt.

Whenever you use `\externalfigure`, ConTeXt makes the dimensions (and number of pages for pdf images) available using the macros `\figurenaturalwidth`, `\figurenaturalheight`, and `\noffigurepages`. If you don't want the image to be included in the document but just want to measure its dimensions, use `\getfiguredimensions`. The following example gets the dimensions for a remote hosted image:

```
\starttext
\getfiguredimensions[http://placekitten.com/500/300][method=png]
\startTABLE
  \NC Width  \NC \the\dimexpr\figurenaturalwidth  \NC \NR
  \NC Height \NC \the\dimexpr\figurenaturalheight \NC \NR
  \NC Pages  \NC \noffigurepages                  \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

`\figurenaturalwidth` and `...height` return the units in `sp`. I use`\the\dimexpr` to convert the result to points. One could also use the Lua function `number.todimen(...)`  for a more versative conversion routine.

**NOTE** As in LaTeX, the dimension calculations use the default DPI specified in pdftex/luatex. So, Jake's comment of comparing `px` and `pt` is still relevant.

Based on the edited question, in ConTeXt you can use:

```
\externalfigure[figurename][maxwidth=\textwidth, maxheight=\textheight]
```

This will shrink the image so that its height and width do not exceed `maxheight` and `maxwidth`. If you need to set these options for many figures, you can use:

```
\defineexternalfigure[MaxWidthAndHeight][maxwidth=\textwidth, maxheight=\textheight]
\externalfigure[figurename][MaxWidthAndHeight][frame=on]
```

(where I used `frame=on` only to show how to add other options, if needed).