# Always scale and clip background image so it fills the page

Tags: graphics, scaling, backgrounds, crop

I have learned from other answers how to [use an image file as background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46281/3213) and [make it transparent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86500/includegraphics-set-image-opacity). Since my background files do not necessarily have the exact page dimensions (they are provided by users), I want to scale and clip them to fit.

I have found, however, that using

```
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio,clip]{#1}
```

does not always scale correctly; landscape-oriented images are scaled so widths fit and then not clipped at all if they are very flat, so a white bar remains. For example, this is using a [1600x750 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6DYU.png) on a US Letter landscape page:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
    \put(0,0){%
      \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio,clip]{test.png}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \phantom{lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I tell `includegraphics` to always scale the shorter dimension to fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't. `adjustbox`, always worth a look, does not seem to offer the necessary option(s), either.

Luckily, we can hack it. Observe that

```
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio,clip]{img}
```

works well for portrait images -- scaling them so the width fits and clip -- and the opposite

```
\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio,clip]{img}%
```

works for landscape images. So we can choose the correct version according to [image dimensions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53500/3213) which version to use:

```
\settoheight\imageheight{\includegraphics{img}}%
\settowidth\imagewidth{\includegraphics{img}}%
\ifthenelse{\dimtest{\imageheight}{>=}{\imagewidth}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio,clip]{img}%
}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio,clip]{img}%
}%
```

Note that this requires package `xifthen`. The example then ends up compiling to:

[image]

I have not figured out yet how to choose a well-defined part of the image, say the middle part, when clipping; it seems to work from the left resp. the bottom by default. Also, the clipped image seems to produce `Overful \hbox` warnings.