# rendering of .jpeg file, wrong size?

Tags: graphics

I am suffering a strange effect: if I try to \includegraphics two .jpeg files with the same properties, they are rendered with different sizes (almost thumbnail vs. actual size) Since this happens at random for a collection of files, I am stuck. I am not sure what I need to check.

```
 \documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}  
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage{lmodern}         
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[american,russian,italian]{babel}
 \usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
 \author{mario  \\ versione 0.1}
   \title{TEST}
   \date{\today}
   \begin{document}
   \maketitle
   \begin{center}
%%\includegraphics[scale=0.225]{img/DSC_0060.JPG}
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/DSC_0060.JPG}
  \end{center}

  \begin{center}
%%\includegraphics[scale=0.225]{img/DSC_0174.JPG}
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{img/DSC_0174.JPG}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

from myfile.log, compare Requested size, why  is 481.79881pt x 724.62543pt vs.  2007.49512pt x 3019.27267pt?

```
 <img/DSC_0060.JPG, id=8, 481.8pt x 724.6272pt>
 File: img/DSC_0060.JPG Graphic file (type jpg)
 <use img/DSC_0060.JPG>
 Package pdftex.def Info: img/DSC_0060.JPG used on input line 22.
 (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 481.79881pt x 724.62543pt.

 Overfull \hbox (91.79881pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--23
 [] 
 []

 [1]
 Overfull \vbox (132.62543pt too high) has occurred while \output is   active []
[2 <./img/DSC_0060.JPG>] <img/DSC_0174.JPG, id=15, 2007.5pt x 3019.28pt>
File: img/DSC_0174.JPG Graphic file (type jpg)
<use img/DSC_0174.JPG>
Package pdftex.def Info: img/DSC_0174.JPG used on input line 27.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 2007.49512pt x 3019.27267pt.  

Overfull \hbox (1617.49512pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 27--28
[] 
[]

[3]
Overfull \vbox (2427.27267pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [] [4 <./img/DSC_0174.JPG>]
```

EDIT [the first answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53497/how-do-i-get-the-exact-dimension-of-a-picture-in-latex) fixes my code nicely (thanks!), but do not address the issue above.

MORE INFO `identify -verbose DSC_0060.JPG`

```
Image: DSC_0060.JPG
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 2000x3008+0+0
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 6.66667x10.0267
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 6016000
    Red:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 215 (0.843137)
        mean: 146.208 (0.573363)
        standard deviation: 21.9552 (0.0860987)
        kurtosis: 12.2775
        skewness: -3.30986
        entropy: 0.717243
    Green:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 202 (0.792157)
        mean: 149.219 (0.585171)
        standard deviation: 25.7637 (0.101034)
        kurtosis: 7.73389
        skewness: -2.47053
        entropy: 0.798522
    Blue:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 209 (0.819608)
        mean: 154.539 (0.606037)
        standard deviation: 31.2284 (0.122464)
        kurtosis: 2.85164
        skewness: -1.37373
        entropy: 0.851679
Image statistics:
    Overall:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 215 (0.843137)
        mean: 149.989 (0.588191)
        standard deviation: 26.5895 (0.104273)
        kurtosis: 6.27469
        skewness: -1.99941
        entropy: 0.789148
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 2000x3008+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Quality: 77
Orientation: TopLeft
Properties:
    date:create: 2016-08-04T14:14:24+02:00
    date:modify: 2010-01-07T23:36:18+01:00
    exif:ColorSpace: 1
    exif:ComponentsConfiguration: 1, 2, 3, 0
    exif:ExifImageLength: 3008
    exif:ExifImageWidth: 2000
    exif:ExifOffset: 102
    exif:ExifVersion: 48, 50, 50, 48
    exif:FlashPixVersion: 48, 49, 48, 48
    exif:InteroperabilityOffset: 204
    exif:MakerNote: 78, 105, 107, 111, 110, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 73, 73, 42, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 48, 50, 49, 48, 17, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 74, 0, 0, 0, 9, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 14, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0, 0, 0, 25, 14, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 60, 0
    exif:Orientation: 1
    exif:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:Compression: 6
    exif:thumbnail:InteroperabilityIndex: R98
    exif:thumbnail:InteroperabilityVersion: 0, 1, 0, 0
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 512
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 1091
    exif:thumbnail:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:XResolution: 300/1
    exif:thumbnail:YResolution: 300/1
    exif:XResolution: 300/1
    exif:YCbCrPositioning: 1
    exif:YResolution: 300/1
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: 6d09810169e82c194b94f8db983a84e558d441971ad4031bc54b69cc33a2523a
Profiles:
    Profile-exif: 15258 bytes
Artifacts:
    filename: DSC_0060.JPG
    verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 702KB
Number pixels: 6.016M
Pixels per second: 1.504TB
User time: 0.000u
Elapsed time: 0:01.000
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

MORE INFO `identify -verbose DSC_0174.JPG`

```
Image: DSC_0174.JPG
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 2000x3008+0+0
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 6.66667x10.0267
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 6016000
    Red:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 225 (0.882353)
        mean: 144.882 (0.568164)
        standard deviation: 14.0253 (0.055001)
        kurtosis: 25.4054
        skewness: -4.05491
        entropy: 0.67539
    Green:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 241 (0.945098)
        mean: 147.549 (0.578623)
        standard deviation: 17.5731 (0.0689142)
        kurtosis: 13.703
        skewness: -2.84547
        entropy: 0.730962
    Blue:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 255 (1)
        mean: 154.287 (0.605049)
        standard deviation: 23.1208 (0.0906698)
        kurtosis: 3.88739
        skewness: -1.3269
        entropy: 0.7888
Image statistics:
    Overall:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 255 (1)
        mean: 148.906 (0.583945)
        standard deviation: 18.6198 (0.0730189)
        kurtosis: 9.99953
        skewness: -1.95921
        entropy: 0.731718
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 2000x3008+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Quality: 77
Orientation: TopLeft
Properties:
    date:create: 2016-08-04T14:14:24+02:00
    date:modify: 2013-06-28T12:21:22+02:00
    exif:ColorSpace: 1
    exif:ComponentsConfiguration: 1, 2, 3, 0
    exif:ExifImageLength: 2000
    exif:ExifImageWidth: 3008
    exif:ExifOffset: 102
    exif:ExifVersion: 48, 50, 50, 48
    exif:FlashPixVersion: 48, 49, 48, 48
    exif:InteroperabilityOffset: 284
    exif:MakerNote: 78, 105, 107, 111, 110, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 73, 73, 42, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 48, 50, 49, 48, 17, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 74, 0, 0, 0, 9, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 14, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0, 0, 0, 25, 14, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 60, 0
    exif:Orientation: 1
    exif:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:Compression: 6
    exif:thumbnail:InteroperabilityIndex: R98
    exif:thumbnail:InteroperabilityVersion: 0, 1, 0, 0
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 408
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 2454
    exif:thumbnail:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:XResolution: 300/1
    exif:thumbnail:YResolution: 300/1
    exif:XResolution: 300/1
    exif:YCbCrPositioning: 1
    exif:YResolution: 300/1
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: c3f1569485cf0cd8522e5648f95bcd85ae41f1fd24c703d4815aeccfa4699c07
Profiles:
    Profile-exif: 2868 bytes
Artifacts:
    filename: DSC_0174.JPG
    verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 619KB
Number pixels: 6.016M
Pixels per second: 1.2032TB
User time: 0.000u
Elapsed time: 0:01.000
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

`identify -verbose    A174.JPG`

```
Image: A174.JPG
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 2000x3008+0+0
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 6.66667x10.0267
Units: Unrecognized
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 6016000
    Red:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 216 (0.847059)
        mean: 146.219 (0.573408)
        standard deviation: 21.9196 (0.0859591)
        kurtosis: 12.2549
        skewness: -3.30845
        entropy: 0.716068
    Green:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 202 (0.792157)
        mean: 149.145 (0.584883)
        standard deviation: 25.7205 (0.100865)
        kurtosis: 7.70369
        skewness: -2.46456
        entropy: 0.797841
    Blue:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 209 (0.819608)
        mean: 154.81 (0.607099)
        standard deviation: 31.3309 (0.122866)
        kurtosis: 2.80184
        skewness: -1.3623
        entropy: 0.852083
Image statistics:
    Overall:
        min: 0 (0)
        max: 216 (0.847059)
        mean: 150.058 (0.588463)
        standard deviation: 26.606 (0.104337)
        kurtosis: 6.22509
        skewness: -1.98185
        entropy: 0.788664
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Interlace: JPEG
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 2000x3008+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Quality: 90
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
    date:create: 2016-08-04T16:15:46+02:00
    date:modify: 2016-08-04T16:15:46+02:00
    exif:ColorSpace: sRGB
    exif:ComponentsConfiguration: 1, 2, 3, 0
    exif:Compression: JPEG compression
    exif:ExifImageLength: 3008
    exif:ExifImageWidth: 2000
    exif:ExifOffset: 102
    exif:ExifVersion: Exif Version 2.2
    exif:FlashPixVersion: FlashPix Version 1.0
    exif:InteroperabilityIndex: R98
    exif:InteroperabilityOffset: 288
    exif:MakerNote: 84 bytes undefined data
    exif:Orientation: Top-left
    exif:PixelXDimension: 2000
    exif:PixelYDimension: 3008
    exif:ResolutionUnit: Inch
    exif:thumbnail:Compression: 6
    exif:thumbnail:InteroperabilityIndex: R98
    exif:thumbnail:InteroperabilityVersion: 0, 1, 0, 0
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 412
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 4578
    exif:thumbnail:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:thumbnail:XResolution: 300/1
    exif:thumbnail:YResolution: 300/1
    exif:XResolution: 300
    exif:YCbCrPositioning: Centered
    exif:YResolution: 300
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: dcec435a0ac186e8c08a5567ecbce4f1d0eae42f62edd0c823600a939e11d164
Profiles:
    Profile-exif: 4996 bytes
    Profile-xmp: 1271 bytes
Artifacts:
    filename: A174.JPG
    verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 883KB
Number pixels: 6.016M
Pixels per second: 668.44GB
User time: 0.000u
Elapsed time: 0:01.000
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

[image: Seen properties by ImageViewer]

Comment: Does this still happen if you swap the order of the files?

Comment: @jake Yes!    No change.

Comment: So it's still the same image that gets scaled down (DSC_0060.JPG)? Could you make the two pictures available?

Comment: @jake, Yes, the same image. No, they are (photo) pictures of private letters. Let me know what would you check of them (besides their properties by GIMP as above)

Comment: Could you run `identify -verbose` from the Imagemagick tools on the two images and post the output in your question? Also, could you try opening the images in GIMP and then saving them using new file names?

Comment: @jake, yes, to open in GIMP and to export them fix the issue. Why so? I have a collection > 1000 of pictures, do I need to open and export each of them?

Comment: I'm not sure yet what's going on, but it's interesting that in `DSC_0174.JPG`, the resolution stated in the `Geometry: 2000x3008+0+0` line doesn't match the one in `exif:ExifImageLength: 2000` and `exif:ExifImageWidth: 3008`. Could you also include the output of `identify -v` on the newly saved versions?  Also, instead of opening/saving all the images in GIMP, you could simply use Imagemagick's `mogrify -path mydirectory *` to the same effect (hopefully).

Comment: @jake see new screenshot. Somehow original 174.jpeg has PixelXd. and PixelYd. swapped, could it be it?

Comment: Yeah, that might be the reason (though it's a bit weird that this throws LaTeX off so badly). Is one of the images in portrait and the other in landscape format? Does running the images through `mogrify` fix the issue?

Comment: @jake. Your main fix from other thread is much better, I am in a hurry, I am not going to mogrify.  I am not sure about landscape/portrait, maybe the original Kodak files were somehow swapped. Thks so much. So good for me.

Comment: Alright, glad that you have a working setup now. Just to make sure there's no misunderstanding, though: You only have to call the `mogrify` command once, it then processes all the images automatically. That shouldn't be too much work, and after that, you can just include the images without any additional code.