# How can I print out the exact dimensions of my images?

Tags: graphics, console

*Please note that while there is an existing question titled "How do I get the exact dimension of a picture in LaTeX?", that question is actually asking something different.*

I have a document that contains several high-resolution png images, included as usual with commands like

```
\includegraphics[width=0.85\columnwidth]{landscape2.png}
```

within figure environments. However, my publisher is asking me for a version where each image is at "no more than 300 dpi, scaled at 100%".

This means, I think, that I have to manually resize all my images. I would like the document to look the same afterwards, so to do that I need to know exactly how much LaTeX is scaling them, or equivalently, the exact dimensions of the image as it appears in my document. That is, I need to know the numerical value of `0.85\columnwidth` in inches, and if possible the height of the image in inches as well.

How can I find this out? I tried `\showthe\columnwidth`, but this gives the following extremely informative error message:

```
?
```

Is it possible to print the exact dimensions of an image, or the scaling ratio used, to the console?

Comment: Store the image in a box: `\setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[..]{...}}`. Then `\showthe\wd1` will print the `w`i`d`th to the terminal, while `\showthe\ht1` will print the `h`eigh`t`. If you want to display these in your document, use `\the\wd1` and `\the\ht1`. The lengths will be in `pt`s. For printing in other lengths, see the [`printlen`](//ctan.org/pkg/printlen) package (or see [How do I get the exact dimension of a picture in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53497/5764)).

Comment: @Werner why did you close my question as a duplicate of that one? Although the *title* of that question sounds like it's the same as mine, the question body is actually completely different, and the answers don't address my issue at all. (That person was actually trying to *set* the size of their image, not print it out, despite what the title says.)

Comment: Also your comment is an answer. Why didn't you just post it as one?

Comment: The linked questions asks how to do both - obtaining the height/width of an image and how to set it. Jake's answer points to using [`printlen`](//ctan.org/pkg/printlen) for getting the image lengths and printing them within your document using the desired dimension. I don't see the difference... anyone else?

Comment: @Nathaniel Jake's answers seems to provide a solution to your problem (imho) -- see the second part.

Comment: @Werner the answer you cite indeed seems to solve my problem, but it does it in a really inconvenient way, requring me to reenter the includegraphics command twice, and printing the answer into the document itself instead of the console. It really would be much easier if you would not block answers from being posted here.

Comment: @Nathaniel This information should by default be in the log file, for example `<example-image.png, id=1, 401.5pt x 301.125pt>
File: example-image.png Graphic file (type png)
 <use example-image.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image.png used on input line 5.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 401.49901pt x 301.12425pt.` Gives you both the original size of the image and the size it will be in the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information in the log file. The following short document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

will tell you in the `.log` file both the original size of the image as well as the size within the document:

```
<example-image-a.pdf, id=1, pagebox=cropbox, 321.2pt x 240.9pt>
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 345.0pt x 258.75659pt on input line 7.

<example-image-b.pdf, id=2, pagebox=cropbox, 321.2pt x 240.9pt>
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 172.5pt x 129.3783pt on input line 9.
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the image in a box:

```
\sbox0{\includegraphics[..]{...}}
```

Then `\showthe\wd0` will print the `w`i`d`th to the *terminal*, while `\showthe\ht0` will print the `h`eigh`t`. If you want to display these in your *document*, use `\the\wd0` and `\the\ht0`. The lengths will be in `pt`s. For printing in other lengths, see the [`printlen` package](//ctan.org/pkg/printlen) (or see [How do I get the exact dimension of a picture in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53497/5764)).