# Rounded box with image and text

Tags: graphics, mdframed, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a rounded box with both text and image. The desired result is as this:

[image: mockup]

Where the image is rounded at the left edges.

I have managed everything except the the image part using `mdframed` as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,bottom=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[shadows]
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{item}{roundcorner=10pt,
                      leftmargin=20pt,
                      rightmargin=20pt,
                      backgroundcolor=gray,
                      innertopmargin=.5em,
                      innerbottommargin=10pt,
                      innerleftmargin=200pt,
                      middlelinewidth=0pt,
                      font=\normalfont\large,
                      shadow=true,
                      frametitlefont=\normalfont\Large\bfseries,
                      frametitleaboveskip=1em}

\begin{document}

\vfill % autospace boxes when there are more than one
\begin{mdframed}[style=item,frametitle=title]
Auto wrapped text aaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaa
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If the image scales to fit height of box and then crops at the text that would be good, but as long as aspect ratio is preserved I can adapt my images to work with most ways.

Any ideas how to proceed from here? Is there a better way than using `mdframed`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The positioning of a picture in the left part can be done by the option `singleextra`. An inspiration of how it works can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52023/mdframed-put-something-on-the-start-of-one-vertical-left-rule/52031#52031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to both the answer from Lionel and Gonzalo together with image scaling from [Scale included graphics to the higher ratio instead of the lower for given width, height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25988/scale-included-graphics-to-the-higher-ratio-instead-of-the-lower-for-given-width) and the `\clip` command for rounding the corners I managed to get what I wanted.

It first creates the text in a box like @LionelMANSUY did and then rescales and rounds the image and inserts it via `singleextra` as in @GonzaloMedina answer

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./meta/} }
\usepackage[margin=0pt,bottom=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary[shadows]
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newlength\ztextheight
\newlength\zimwidth\setlength{\zimwidth}{130pt}      % Image width
\newlength\zimmargin\setlength{\zimmargin}{20pt}     % Image<>Text margin
\newlength\ztextwidth\setlength{\ztextwidth}{530pt}  % Text width
\newlength\zrradius\setlength{\zrradius}{10pt}       % Rounding radius

\newlength\zitemmargin
\setlength{\zitemmargin}{\zimwidth+\zimmargin}

\newsavebox{\zitembox}
% Usage: \zitem{title}{body}{image.jpg}
\newcommand{\zitem}[3]{
  \savebox{\zitembox}{\parbox{\ztextwidth-\zitemmargin}{%
    \vspace{10pt}        % top inner margin
    \textbf{\Large #1}
    \vspace{5pt}\newline % title/text margin
    \large #2
    \vspace{10pt}        % bottom inner margin
  }}
  \settototalheight{\ztextheight}{\usebox{\zitembox}}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=item,
    singleextra={
      % Crop image, rounding the left corners
      \clip (\zimwidth,0pt) -- (\zimwidth, \ztextheight)
          {[rounded    corners=\zrradius] -- (0pt,\ztextheight) -- 
            (0,0pt) -- (\zimwidth,0)};
      % Scale image to fill both width and height
      \node at (.5\zimwidth,.5\ztextheight) {
        \adjustbox{min size={\zimwidth}{\ztextheight}}{
          \includegraphics[max size={\zimwidth}{\ztextheight}]{#3}
      }};
    }]
    \usebox{\zitembox}
   \end{mdframed}
}

% Those marked with % are required to stay fixed
\mdfdefinestyle{item}{roundcorner=\zrradius,
                      leftmargin=20pt,
                      rightmargin=20pt,
                      backgroundcolor=white,
                      innertopmargin=0,%
                      innerbottommargin=0pt,%
                      innerleftmargin=\zitemmargin,%
                      middlelinewidth=0pt,
                      font=\normalfont\large,
                      shadow=true,
                      skipbelow=10pt,
                      skipabove=10pt
}


\begin{document}
\zitem{Title}{\lipsum[1] text}{lena.jpg}
\zitem{Title 2}{\lipsum[4]}{sailboat.jpg}
\zitem{Title 3}{\lipsum[2-3]}{clock.jpg}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 7):

Without using extra boxes, you can simply use `singleextra` (for non-breaking frames) and TikZ `\node` and `\draw` commands, to draw the vertical rule and place the image at the desired position; a complete example (of course, adjust the used lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,bottom=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[shadows]
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\mdfdefinestyle{item}{roundcorner=10pt,
  leftmargin=20pt,
  rightmargin=20pt,
  backgroundcolor=gray,
  innertopmargin=.5em,
  innerbottommargin=10pt,
  innerleftmargin=200pt,
  middlelinewidth=0pt,
  font=\normalfont\large,
  shadow=true,
  frametitlefont=\normalfont\Large\bfseries,
  frametitleaboveskip=1em,
  singleextra={
   \draw[black,ultra thick] 
     ([xshift=190pt]P-|O) -- ([xshift=190pt]O);
  \path let \p1 = ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ ) in   
    (\the\dimexpr0.5\mdflength{innerleftmargin}\relax,\y1) coordinate (Q);  
  \node at (Q) {\includegraphics[width=\the\dimexpr0.7\mdflength{innerleftmargin}\relax]{verde}};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=item,frametitle=title]
\lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{mdframed}[style=item,frametitle=title]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting document:

[image]

One then could also use `firstextra`, `secondextra`, etc. if frames must split, and if the image will have to go in one specific place.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>In my opinion, it could be difficult to position your picture with your proposition.</strike>

I would suggest to proceed in a different way:

1/ Typeset your text in a saved box in order to compute the height of the text

```
\newsavebox{\tmpbox}
\savebox{\tmpbox}{\parbox{...width...}{...content...}}
```

2/ Assuming you know the maximal width of your picture, you will be able to include the picture with the right aspect ratio. I'm using a `\parbox` to center it toward the baseline.
Notice that you need the `calc` package

```
\newlength\mymeasure
\settototalheight{\mymeasure}{\usebox{\tmpbox}}
\parbox{...maxwidth...}{%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=...maxwidth...,height=\mymeasure,keepaspectratio]{...picture path...}%
}
\usebox{\tmpbox} % use the text box
```

3/ you can put the above lines in the `mdframed` to draw the frame

**Exemple:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary[shadows]
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\mdfdefinestyle{item}{roundcorner=10pt,
                      leftmargin=20pt,
                      rightmargin=20pt,
                      backgroundcolor=gray,
                      innermargin=10pt,
                      shadow=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=item]
\newsavebox{\tmpbox}
\savebox{\tmpbox}{\parbox{.5\columnwidth}{%
    \textbf{\Large Title}

    Auto wrapped text aaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa a aaa a aaaaa aaaa
}}

\newlength\mymeasure
\settototalheight{\mymeasure}{\usebox{\tmpbox}}
\parbox{.4\columnwidth}{%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=.3\columnwidth,height=\mymeasure,keepaspectratio]{test}%
}
\usebox{\tmpbox}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]