# Equal size subfigure

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats, height

I want my subfigures to look uniform, thus each having same width and height.
Additionally, each of the two rows should have a center, around which all subfigures in that row are centered.

I want that to happen automatically without fiddling with height, width and scale parameters until everything fits.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\iffalse
\begin{overpic}[grid,tics=10,width=\textwidth]{pictures/reflectors/whiteboard-back/frontal.jpg}
\end{overpic}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{overpic}[grid,tics=10,trim=20 10 20 0,width=\textwidth]{pictures/reflectors/whiteboard-back/frontal.jpg}
\end{overpic}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{overpic}[grid,tics=10,trim=20 10 20 0,clip,width=\textwidth]{pictures/reflectors/whiteboard-back/frontal.jpg}
\end{overpic}
\fi

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[\SI{30}{\degree} left]{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{results/rp/glassdoor-aac-30deg_left_rp.pdf}} \qquad
\subfloat[\SI{30}{\degree} right]{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{results/rp/glassdoor-aac-30deg_right_rp.pdf}} \qquad
\subfloat[\SI{60}{\degree} left]{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{results/rp/glassdoor-aac-60deg_left_rp.pdf}} \qquad
\subfloat[\SI{60}{\degree} right]{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{results/rp/glassdoor-aac-60deg_right_rp.pdf}} \qquad
\subfloat[\SI{90}{\degree}]{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{results/rp/glass-door-90deg_rp.pdf}} \qquad
\subfloat[Measurement location]{\includegraphics[angle=-90,origin=c,height=0.4\textwidth]{pictures/reflectors/glassdoor/frontal.jpg}} \qquad
\caption{Range measurements for clear glass at 30,60,90 degree angles of incidence from the left and the right side}
\label{fig:rp_glassdoor}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! For your subfigure (f): do you intend to crop it, or to "deform" it? (I don't think the latter would suit your needs). If all your subfigures don't have the same ratio, it will be hard to define one rule for all...

Comment: I would like the subfigure with the photo to take the height of the graphs. If it were in landscape mode, I would like it to take the width of the graphs. On addition to that it should be centered, e.g. in this case the centre of the image should be underneath the marker "5" in the above plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggested (even if bulky) answer.
[image]

- **centering:** It uses `\minipages` (since you already know it will be 3 rows and 2 colums) + `\hfill`, and `\adjustbox`es with `valign=t,center` option for centering the last one.
- **adequate size** We use the trick given in [Scale included graphics to the higher ratio instead of the lower for given width, height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25992/64454) : using the `keepaspectratio` option of `\includegraphics`, combined with defining a (max) `width` and `height` (according to the ratio (a) to (e) pictures : I assumed here that they are 3/4 -- hence `width = 0.75\textwidth`)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\SI{30}{\degree} left]{\includegraphics[height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\SI{30}{\degree} right]{\includegraphics[height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\SI{60}{\degree} left]{\includegraphics[height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \subfloat[\SI{60}{\degree} right]{\includegraphics[height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                \centering
                \subfloat[\SI{90}{\degree}]{\includegraphics[height=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
            \end{minipage}
        }
        \adjustbox{valign=t, center}{
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}% 
                \subfloat[Measurement location]{\includegraphics[angle=-90, origin=c, height=\textwidth, width = 0.75\textwidth,  keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}%
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{minipage}

\caption{Range measurements for clear glass at 30,60,90 degree angles of incidence from the left and the right side}
\label{fig:rp_glassdoor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Image B should be aligned with the upper edge of the bottom-left A image.

Comment: @cschmol done (-;

Comment: thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for ;) I think I cannot upvote or accept the answer as I do not have enough "reputation" for that :(

Comment: Indeed, you need to reach [15 rep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to vote up. However, I think you can already [accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). Anyway, I'm glad it helped! `(-:`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution.  I used \tempheight to equalize the heights and \raisebox to align the bottoms.  The only adjustment needed is to fit the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{showframe}% check centering
    \newlength{\tempheight}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \settoheight{\tempheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \hfil\begin{tabular}{cc}
      \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\
      \SI{30}{\degree} left & \SI{30}{\degree} right \\[1ex]
      \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\
      \SI{60}{\degree} left & \SI{60}{\degree} right \\[1ex]
      \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
        \raisebox{\depth}{\includegraphics[width=\tempheight, angle=-90]{example-image-b}} \\
      \SI{90}{\degree} & Measurement location
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Range measurements for clear glass at 30,60,90 degree angles of incidence from the left and the right side}
\label{fig:rp_glassdoor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Can it be a problem that this solution is not using subfigures?

Comment: Subfigures are just renamed minipages.  I've never seen any point in using them.